# I need a XML Element of a XML Element

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

Lets pretend i have the following XML.

```
<xml>
 ...
 <tag>
  <othertag>
  </othertag>
 </tag>
 ...
</xml>
```

What i want is to "extract" the

```
<tag>
  <othertag>
  </othertag>
 </tag>
```

into another Variable.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<xml>
 <SomeTag test="x"/>
 <SomeTag test="y"/>
 <tag>
  <othertag>
  </othertag>
 </tag>
 <SomeTag test="z"/>
</xml>';
```

If possible, be as specific as possible

```
DECLARE @xml2 XML = @xml.query('(/xml/tag)[1]');

SELECT @xml2;
```

If not, you might go the lazy way...

```
DECLARE @xml3 XML = @xml.query('//tag');

SELECT @xml3;
```